# What are Mother Dark and Father Light?

Tags: malazan

I just finished Dust of Dreams and, interestingly, the list of Elder Gods summoned by Errastas doesn't include Mother Dark, Father Light, or Tiam. Are they older than the Elder Gods?

Comment: If I remember correctly from the prequel books, the kharkanas trilogy Mother Dark was the "queen" or something of the tiste andi and Father light was a general of the tiste army named urusander that became liosan when some dark priestesses defected. I forget why they defected and became liosan. But urusander was kind of just pulled along with the events. I would check out the prequel trilogy when you get a chance. It tellls where all the tiste came from.

Comment: Thanks! Gotta finish Crippled God first, though.

Comment: Yea they are amazing books. Mother dark and father light are not older than the elder gods. Tiam might be. Def read the prequels when you get a chance. I think tiam is a dragon if remember correctly.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace the amazing part is up for debate. There is a reason the third book in the prequel series has been put on hold.